# Use of ```self.[]``` in method definition in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Actually, I am experienced in NodeJS but I am very new to Ruby, I cannot understand how this piece of ruby code is working, can someone explain what exactly the `self.call` method and `self.[]` methods are doing in this Ruby code ?.

```
1. class Mine::Container
2. 
3. def self.call
4.    @containers || {}
5. end
6.
7. def self.[] namespace
8.    @containers ||= Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = new }
9.    @containers[namespace]
10.  end
11.end
```

What exactly `self.call`, `self.[]` method is doing ?.
What would I get back if I call `Mine::Container.().` ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mine::Container.()` is a shortcut for `Mine::Container.call` that means it would call the `call` class method which looks like this:

```
def self.call
  @containers || {}
end
```

And it returns the value of `@containers` if `@containers` is it is set, otherwise (if `@containers` is not `nil` or `false`) an empty hash is returned (`{}`).

Furthermore the `def self.[] namespace` defines a class method to that expect one argument `namespace` which can be called like this:

```
Mine::Container[namespace]
```

Comment: So it is storing the value of containers in memory right for example If I run this code and add 2 containers in it, having namespace 'IT' and add another 2 containers having namespace 'GH', then If I restart the application, I will lose all that data right ?.

Comment: Also I would request you to please let me know what does the code in line number 8 is doing ?.

Comment: @NishkarshKumar in line 8 it will assign a new hash if `@containers` is nil or falsy and in next line it is returning the key which is being requested, since key will not exists in first request there is another piece of code `{|h, k| h[k] = new }` which is telling what to return as default value which is `Mine::Container` instance, with each call if the key is not present then new instance will be assigned to that specific key and will be return and in the next call the key will be present and the assigned value will be returned.